# Detect app first launch windows phone

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8

I'm quite new on windows phone dev. I would like to detect when the user launches my app for the first time to display an explaination frame for example by calling :

```
if(firstLaunch)
showTheFrameToTheGuyBecauseHeLaunchedTheAppForTheFirstTime();
```

I would be sooooooo glad if someone could show us such a small script...

Thank you in advance guys !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend you to use the builtin applicationsettings.

```
const string settingsAppLaunched = "appLaunched";

public static bool IsFirstLaunch(){
    IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
    return !(settings.Contains(settingsAppLaunched) && settings[settingsAppLaunched]);
}

public static bool Launched(){
    if(IsFirstLaunch()){
        IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
        settings.Add(settingsAppLaunched, true);
        settings.Save();
    }
}

//usage:
if(IsFirstLaunch()){
    showTheFrameToTheGuyBecauseHeLaunchedTheAppForTheFirstTime();
    Launched();
}
```

Microsoft Documentation about Settings in Windows Phone is available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj714090(v=vs.105).aspx).

Comment: This answered my question, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use IsolatedStorageSettings.

```
if(!IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("first"))
{
   // Do your stuff
   IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["first"] = true;
   IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
}
```

This code will do it.