# Xamarin Forms Current.Properties

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

When I store strings in the Current.Properties, everything works but when I uninstall the windows phone app and reinstall it the Current.Properties keys still seem to be on the device.

My question is how do I clear the Current.Properties keys when the app is uninstalled on a windows phone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we have to find out where Forms is storing the data.
A quick look at the [source code](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/2.3.2/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WinRT/WindowsSerializer.cs) shows, that it is stored in the roaming folder in the file `PropertyStore.forms`.

I don't know any uninstall detection. Thats why wy approach would be to delete the properties on the first launch of the app. **The example code is for Windows Phone 8.1**, On other Windows Phone platforms, you have to [store the first launch flag differently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25107414/1489968).

**App.xaml.cs**

```cs
public sealed partial class App : Application
{
    const string settingsAppLaunched = "appLaunched";

    public static bool IsFirstLaunch()
    {
        var settings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
        return !settings.Values.ContainsKey(settingsAppLaunched);
    }

    protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
    {           
        // ...

        if (rootFrame == null)
        {
            // ...
            Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e);

            if (IsFirstLaunch())
            {
                var settings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
                settings.Values[settingsAppLaunched] = true;
                Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.Properties.Clear();
            }
        }           
        // ..
    }
}
```